# private method `open' called for URI:Module ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

Working with a gem but its throwing an error on an older build

```
private method `open' called for URI:Module
```

Extracted source (around line #135):
133
134
135
136
137
138

```
  url = construct_url(path)
  #URI::open(url, read_timeout: 600).read
  URI.open(url, read_timeout: 600).read
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e
  if error = JSON.load(e.io.read)["error"]
    puts "server returns error for url: #{url}"
```

I'm running Rails 4.2.6  on Ruby ruby 2.3.8p459

Im a LOT out of my depth here :(

this is the code that calls the error in the gem
I unpacked and rebuilt with the comment out above as can't find documentation bth URI::open( and URI.open throw same error, private method called.

```
                require 'google_search_results' 
            require 'open-uri'
    
            params = {
              q: @q,
              location: "United Kingdom",
              hl: "en",
              gl: "uk",
              google_domain: "google.co.uk",
              api_key: ENV["google_search_api_key"],
              num: 20
            }
    
            search = GoogleSearch.new(params)
            @hash_results = search.get_hash
```

I know its to do with the version of Rails / Ruby Im running but don't know where to look or terminology of question to ask.

Comment: Strangely that is a [documented method](https://rubyapi.org/3.0/o/uri#method-c-open).

Comment: Thanks didn't know how to search or where documentation was held :)

Comment: What I mean is it's documented as being public, but if it isn't, that is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method like that [from ruby 2.4 onwards](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html), but for [2.3](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) you should just use it as:

```
open(url, read_timeout: 600).read
```